# Google Chrome Developer Tools - Disable the new device emulation ruler without turning off emulation

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, rulers

As many others, I also want to get rid of the new device emulation ruler in Chrome/Chromium Dev Tools.
But I still want to keep device emulation, because I need to have the website I work on at a specific resolution (more exactly at a specific width). However the rulers are just a distraction most of the time, and the interface is occupying valuable vertical screen space.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't at this time.

Thanks for the feedback though. We're working on a solution for hiding much of the UI when not needed – most likely, we'll start with a 'mini' mode that makes the rulers smaller and collapses emulation into a single row.

Work in progress can be seen here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=409607 (also the best place for further feedback)